# Why is the Bogoliubov transform unitary of $H\oplus H$

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics

In Bach, V., Lieb, E.H. & Solovej, J.P. J Stat Phys (1994) 76: 3. https://doi-org.stanford.idm.oclc.org/10.1007/BF02188656, page 10, the Bogoliubov transform on the Fock space $\mathscr{F}$ is a unitary operator $\mathscr{W}$ such that
$$
d^* (f)\equiv \mathscr{W} c^*(f) \mathscr{W}^* = c^*(uf) + c(v\bar{f})
$$
where $u,v$ are linear operators, $f\mapsto \bar{f}$ is the complex conjugation (relative to some fixed orthonormal basis $e_i$) and $f\in \mathscr{H}$, the Hilbert space describing single particle state. The article then claims that if such a Bogoliubov transform exists, then the corresponding operator on $\mathscr{H}\oplus\mathscr{H}$ must be unitary

$$
W=
\begin{bmatrix}
u &v\\
\bar{v} &\bar{u}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since $\mathscr{W}$ is unitary, it's clear that $d^*(f)$ satisfies the canonical anticommutation relations and thus it's straightforward to show that $W$ is isometric, i.e., $W^*W = I$. However, I'm having trouble proving that it is surjective, i.e., $WW^* =I$.

EDIT: Just a thought, but I think the key is to prove that $\mathscr{W}^*$ is also a Bogoliubov transform of the fermionic Fock space. Either that, or we need to redefine the Bogoliubov transform as such that both $\mathscr{W}$ and $\mathscr{W}^*$ satisfy a similar equality.

Comment: Does $\overline{u}u-\overline{v}v=I$ hold?

Comment: @ValterMoretti It's not a given condition.